# What does the code illustration visible on StackOverflow's 404 page do?

Tags: c

If you hit any non-existent page on SO, like https://stackoverflow.com/not-found, you'll see a small code snippet on the right side of the page (as an illustration)

What exactly does this piece of code do? (I'm asking simply out of curiosity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might get closed as a duplicate on meta too, since it's been answered [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38236/what-is-the-code-on-stackoverflow-page-not-found-pages). The suggestion for it is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27112/amusing-404-page-not-found-images-for-trilogy-sites).